# How to do auto increment for datagridview cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, auto-increment

Some columns of my DataGridView are loaded from a database. Also, I added some columns to that DataGridView manually. I want to increment the value for every cell in first column named as "S_No".

I hope code will clarify my issue:

```
private void bindgrid()
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 12;
    ConnectionStringSettings consettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"];
    string connectionString = consettings.ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    cn.Open();

    string dtp = dateTimePicker3grd.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    string query = "select s_no,Employee_id,Employee_name from Employee_Details where employee_id not in (select employee_id from dailyattendance where date = '" + dtp + "') order by S_No ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {
            sda.Fill(dt);

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "S_No";
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "S_No";//*Here I Want to increment cell value by 1 for every cell..and the first cell of the column should be the last serial value of database*
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Employee_id";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Employee_Id";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Employee_id";

            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Employee_name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Employee_Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Employee_name";

            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "In_time";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "In_time";

            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Out_time";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Out_time";

            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Date";
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Date";

            dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "Week_no_of_the_Month";
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Week_no_of_the_Month";


            dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Attendance";
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].Name = "Attendance";

            dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Image_of_the_Employee";
            dataGridView1.Columns[8].Name = "Image_of_the_Employee";

            dataGridView1.Columns[9].Name = "Image_path";
            dataGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Image_path";

            dataGridView1.Columns[10].Name = "Work_status";
            dataGridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = "Work_status";

            dataGridView1.Columns[11].Name = "Remarks";
            dataGridView1.Columns[11].HeaderText = "Remarks";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do that in the `DataTable` not the `DataGridView`.  If you configure it in the database then the `DataTable` will take on the same properties automatically, although you may have to set the `MissingSchemaAction` property of your data adapter to `AddWithKey`.  Id that column set to be an identity in SQL Server?  If not then it probably should be, because that's how you auto-increment IDs.

Comment: By the way, why is everything using local variables in that method?  Surely you need to keep references to the `DataTable` and data adapter in order to save the data afterwards.

Comment: please update my code which helps me better way,As I am learner I don't know how to use datatable,Will u please edit my code using datatable @jmcilhinney

Comment: In your code After the line ' sda.Fill(dt);' add the following lines of code . please check if that works for you. later you can add the exception checks whether you got the records from the query or not kind of ..  
     int maxSlNo = int.Parse(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["s_no"].ToString());
 maxSlNo++;
 foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
  {
     dtRow["s_no"] = maxSlNo;
     maxSlNo++;
  }
dt.AcceptChanges();
If this works for you please let me know i will add this as answer

Comment: this is not working @kishoreVM

Comment: please add more details of what is not working , is it throwing any error .. also i suggest you need to check whether you missed dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "s_no";    // also please check the case of "s_no" in the above code sinppet

Comment: Ya you are right 
I missed dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "s_no"
now its working thank you..
now you can add as answer..@kishoreVM

Comment: Good to hear that it worked for you. I have added my comments as answer.please mark this as answered. Good luck ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code After the line `sda.Fill(dt);` add the following lines of code. Please check if that works for you. Later you can add the exception checks whether you got the records from the query or not.

```
int maxSlNo = int.Parse(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["s_no"].ToString());
maxSlNo++;
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
{
    dtRow["s_no"] = maxSlNo;
    maxSlNo++;
}

dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Also, add the following line:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "s_no";
```